# BigQuery: Is it possible to change _PARTITIONTIME to my current timezone?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Python's to_gbq to upload my csv to BQ table. However, when I tried to query today's _PARTITIONTIME, I could not find any data:

```
SELECT * FROM `aaa.bbb.ccc` WHERE TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(_PARTITIONTIME, DAY) = TIMESTAMP("2023-07-31")
```

It's all Because my time zone was UTC+8, So BigQuery actually think I uploaded data from "2023-07-30".

Is there any other way I can change my _PARTITIONTIME directly from my BQ to UTC+8? I think the default is UTC, not sure if it's changable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When insert data to BQ, just change the table name to something like 'aaa.bbb.ccc$20230731', then the problem is solved.

Pyhton code:

```
date=datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')    
table = f'aaa.bbb.ccc${date}'
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(
    dataframe,
    table,
    project_id,
    if_exists='append',
    table_schema=schema,
    api_method='load_csv'
)
```